# QMultiHash php, same key, multiple values

Tags: php, qt, hash

I try to convert some code from C++/Qt to php.  The original code has some hash like this:

`QMultiHash<int, QString> Var;`

It means that there can be many values associated to the same key, and at the same time, like:

0 => "Zero"

0 => "0"

0 => "etc."

How can it be done in php?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$multiHash = array(0 => array("Zero", "0", "etc."));
?>

//c++
bool    contains ( const Key & key, const T & value ) const
//php
bool    in_array ( $value, $multiHash[$key] )

//c++
bool    contains ( const Key & key ) const
//php
bool    array_key_exists ( $key, $multiHash )

//c++
QHash<Key, T>::iterator insert ( const Key & key, const T & value )
//php
void    $multiHash[$key][] = $value
int     array_push ( $multiHash[$key], $value )
```

etc..